# JOIN query only returning 1st row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve multiple rows from joining two tables where store.itemid = item_list.id.

```
$query = "SELECT s.price, il.*  
    FROM store s LEFT JOIN item_list il ON s.itemid = il.id";
```

I then have:

```
if($result = $conn->($query)) {
    $array = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    }
```

With my current code, the query is only retrieving the first row from the 'store' table. I have made certain that there should definitely be more than one row to return.

print_r($array) shows:

```
Array ( [price] => 400 [id] => 5 [name] => Computer )
```

Comment: When you are doing print_r($array); is there more then one result in the array ?

Comment: No, there's only one result. I'll update post to show result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are only running fetch_array() once. You probably need to run it in a loop, e.g.:

```
if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
    while ($array = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // do something with $array
    }
}
```

Comment: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) ...`

Comment: i did not see your code first. so i thought i give a small example in addition. you are very right!

Comment: Thanks! You were very right. I've never had to loop through a mysql query before.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
$array = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

use this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 //put your code here!
}
```